# Is there a way to search through embedded arrays using aggregate pipeline in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to search through all the arrays within the categories field to find if the product belongs in the 'T-Shirt' category, is there a way to search through all the arrays within the category field?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
// Aggregate Pipeline
db.products.aggregate([
  {$group :
    {_id :
      {productID : '$productID', productTitle : '$productTitle ', categories: '$categories'
    }
  }
},
  {$project :
      {
          category_tshirts : {$in : ['T-Shirts', '$_id.categories']}
      }
   }
]);
```

**Here is an example of one of the documents:**

```
// Example document
{
        "productID" : "B000072SJ2",
        "productTitle" : "Loosegear Short Sleeve",
        "categories" : [ 
            [ 
                "Sports & Outdoors", 
                "Clothing", 
                "Men", 
                "Shirts", 
                "T-Shirts"
            ], 
            [ 
                "Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", 
                "Men", 
                "Clothing", 
                "Shirts"
            ], 
            [ 
                "Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", 
                "Men", 
                "Big & Tall"
            ]
        ]
    }
```

Comment: You can try unwind the `'$_id.categories'`after the group stage and then, search using the `$in`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You may use the [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator in order to get rid of nested arrays.

This operator allows you to have as many separate documents as items in the selected array. For example, having this document:

```
{
  "productID" : "B00006I551",
  "productTitle" : "CASIO F91W-1 Casual Sport Watch",
  "categories" : [ 
     [ 
       "Sports & Outdoors", 
       "Accessories", 
       "Sport Watches"
     ], 
     [ 
       "Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", 
       "Sport Watches"
     ], 
     [ 
        "Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", 
        "Men"
     ]
   ]
 }
```

If you use unwind on the `categories` field:

`db.products.aggregate( [ { $unwind : "$categories" } ] )`

You will get 3 almost similar documents, where only categories are different (1 doc for each item in top level array):

```
{
  "productID" : "B00006I551",
  "productTitle" : "CASIO F91W-1 Casual Sport Watch",
  "categories" : [ 
       "Sports & Outdoors", 
       "Accessories", 
       "Sport Watches"
     ]
 },
{
  "productID" : "B00006I551",
  "productTitle" : "CASIO F91W-1 Casual Sport Watch",
  "categories" : [ 
       "Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", 
       "Sport Watches"
     ]
 },
{
  "productID" : "B00006I551",
  "productTitle" : "CASIO F91W-1 Casual Sport Watch",
  "categories" : [ 
        "Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", 
        "Men"
     ]
 }
```

Now you may use the `$in` operator or other ways for querying and filtering via `categories`.